# Stripping Left and Right of character

Tags: php

What would be the best way to strip left and right of characters in php? I have it stripping right but cant figure out left. I tried ltrim but it doesnt seem to work well.

```
$rawsubject = 'RE: [#4152] - Registration Issues';
$casenumber_param="]";
$casenumber_strip = strpos($rawsubject,$casenumber_param);
$casenumber = substr($rawsubject,0,$casenumber_strip);
```

output currently is: `RE: [#4152`

I need to strip everything left of `[#` so all I am left with is `4152`.

Comment: Have you tried RegExp to pull out the digits inside `[ ]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few ways you could do this, but it's probably best if you go with a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html). This one behaves exactly like your current code: find the closing square bracket and isolate all consecutive digits that come just before it.

```
if (preg_match('/\d+(?=\])/', $rawsubject, $matches)) {
    $casenumber = $matches[0];
}
```

It's very probable that you would prefer something more direct, such as "grab the digits between the square brackets":

```
if (preg_match('/\[#(\d+)\]/', $rawsubject, $matches)) {
    $casenumber = $matches[1];
}
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/cKYTj)**.

Answer (score 0):

The logical extension of your current code is just to do the other side:

```
$rawsubject = 'RE: [#4152] - Registration Issues';
$casenumber_start="#";
$casenumber_end="]";
$start = strpos($rawsubject,$casenumber_start)+1;
$end  = strpos($rawsubject,$casenumber_end);
$casenumber = substr($rawsubject,$start,$end-$start);
```

But I would go with a regex-based solution.

Answer (score 0):

to strip those with ltrim you need to write it like this:

```
$rawsubject = ltrim($rawsubject, "RE:[# ");
```